# I have a b" " format , i cant split it

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I grabbed an email body from Gmail Imap server. Now That File contain format like b"some line /d/n  some line /d/n". Mine aim is to get that some line by anyway. but I am unable to do that.

I tried Split() method but that does not works.

```
def main():
    yes = open("file.txt", "r")
    byte_object= yes.read()
    print(byte_object.decode('utf8')) #Nothing changes

main()
```

I expect output as Lines between those tags

Comment: Are you sure it is `"/d/n"`, not `"\d\n"`?

Comment: Yes. Let me Give You File Format. (''b"Google Logo\r\n\r\n\r\nThis is Text Message\r\n\r\n") this is File Text, i wana grab Text, such as "this is Text Message There .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found Mine answer. it was easy :) 
Well This is code to get those lines

```
    yes = 'b"Google Logo\r\n\r\n\r\nYHello This is message \r\n\r\n"'
    Yes2 = yes.decode('UTF8')
    for f in Yes2.split("\r\n\r"):
       print(f)
```

So this will print Line except those "/n/r" codes :)

Answer (score -1):

Similar question: [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

The example provided there is: `b'\xE2\x82\xAC'.decode('UTF-8')`. Note, use capital UTF and put a dash in between.

Comment: 1st Of all Thanks for commenting Here, But i checked that post and i tried but still not working in mine case (b"Google Logo\r\n\r\n\r\nYHello This is message \r\n\r\n") This is Format.